# Meteor.userId() returns the value of login user but Meteor.user() is undefined in meteor 1.5

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-blaze

Here is the html:

```
<div>
    <span id="login-entrance">{{loginEntranceContent}}</span>
</div>
```

Here is the client side js code:

```
loginEntranceContent(){
    if (Meteor.userId()==null) {
        return 'Log in/Sign up';
    } else {
            Meteor.user().emails.address;
    };
},
```

Now I am sure that the user is logged in because when I tried Meteor.userId(),it returns the value of the _id of current user. But the Meteor.user() turns out to be undefined. I assume that the Meteor.user() result should automatically updated later. so I waited for a while,but it didn't update neither in my chrome browser.

And I know the problem has something to do with the fact that the DOM rendered before the data is ready. But I don't know what exactly is going on there.

I already went around the forum for answers, there were some similar topic but none had provided a clear explanation and simple solution for it. So I hope it is worthwhile to open a new topic for it.

FYI, to solve it ,I tried to make a method on server side :

```
Meteor.users.findOne({_id:'this.userId'});
```

and called it from the client side. it still get the undefined result....

Comment: Your else-part does not return anything AND `Meteor.user().emails.address`does not exist because emails is an array so the only way could be `Meteor.user().emails[0].address`. Using this.userId in quotes makes it a string so it tries to find a user, that has the id `'this.userId'`. If you leave the quotes it should find a user with your userId. You may read more about JS syntax and semantics to improve your understanding of the language's concepts.

Comment: I totally forgot email property is an array. my dumb question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are making jsut a `null` check, what about other '**falsy**' value checks, you must properly use the code as below,

```
loginEntranceContent(){
    if (!Meteor.userId()) {
        return 'Log in/Sign up';
    } else if(Meteor.user() && Meteor.user().emails && Meteor.user().emails[0].address){
            return Meteor.user().emails[0].address;
    } else {
        //do something here.
    };
},
```

and as you have not shown us the code to call Meteor method from client, as @Jankapunkt suggested use code as below at server end,

```
Meteor.users.findOne({_id : this.userId});
```

> **Note**: Meteor provides a beautiful API for managing [User-Accounts](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#accounts-ui)